# Is there anyway to have text updated in a program/application in real time as I type into a 2nd program?

Tags: notepad++

I want to be able to type out what I need in notepad++ because of it's simplicity of use. However, I want that same text to be changing in chrome as I do it (in code2flow). Is this possible?
Edit: Alternatively, is there any similar and simple but better flow chart making application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no ready-to-use application that does what you specifically ask, what you might look up is how to inject some basic javascript, then with that javascript poll the data from your favourite editor, you'll need to make some middleware application for that, in you editor you make a extension/plugin that sends the typed data to the middleware app. the middleware app can probably be combined with the extension/plugin. So this looks like a whole project. Is it worth it? To be decided by you.